# the import com.google.gms.drive.internal.r cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I'm importing an android project in android studio, but that project shows an error in line
`import com.google.android.gms.drive.internal.r;` it says cannot find symbol r. I have search possible answer but still cannot resolved this issue. some I had done:

- re-import google-play-service_lib.jar
- adding some dependencies in the gradle
- closing project and delete the .iml file and .idea project
- sync project with gradle
- invalidate caches and restart project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.jar` if you are on Android Studio. And for Google Play Services use this:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'`

or find what you from : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: thank you, It works. I remark the import and add the dependencies